# Django returning 403 Error -- "CSRF cookie not set"

Tags: python, html, django, post

I'm getting a 405 error, specifically saying `CSRF verification failed. Request aborted. CSRF cookie not set.`

My `urls.py` is:

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from django.contrib import admin
from users.views import HandlerView
admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^users/login$', HandlerView.as_view(), name='my-view'),
    url(r'^users/add$', HandlerView.as_view(), name='my-view'),
)
```

and my `views.py` is:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.views.generic import View

class HandlerView(View):
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return HttpResponse('Hello, World!')

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        print "Hello world!"
        return HttpResponse('Hello, World!')
```

The curl execution that I'm inputting at my terminal is:

```
curl -v -H "Accept: application/json" -H "Content-type: application/json" -X POST -d ' {"user" : "jeff", "password" : "pass1"} ' http://localhost:8000/users/add
```

and the terminal running my server returns:

```
[13/Feb/2014 00:38:06] "POST /users/add HTTP/1.1" 403 2282
```

I understand what CSRF is, but what would this be flagging for a POST method through the terminal, when theres no cookies right? What would be the remedy to this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It might be giving this error because you might be having the CSRF protection turned on in middelware settings.

If you don't need that protection, you can set the view as [CSRF exempt](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/csrf/).
You can simply use a decorator on the view or you can turn it disable it from middleware settings.

```
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt
from django.http import HttpResponse

@csrf_exempt
def my_view(request):
    return HttpResponse('Hello world')
```