# CSRF verification failed. Request aborted - Serving a Django template as Server-Side Include

Tags: python, django, nginx, django-forms, uwsgi

I've been at this for a few hours. I'm relatively new with Django and I need help in a setup that doesn't seem all that common.

I'm serving my website with Nginx and UWSGI where most of the pages are static and not served using Django. The only reason I'm using Django is for implementing a form. Therefore, I decided to SSI just the form template itself into a <div> within an existing HTML outside of the Django server. The form actually works great when DEBUG = True, but when False the form would render but throws an error when trying to submit. The error is "Forbidden (403) CSRF verification failed. Request aborted. Reason given for failure: CSRF cookie not set." Now the solutions I've found only assume that the whole website is served by Django. However, for me, only a snippet of Django template is served using Nginx's SSI. I'm wondering what the issue is and if the community can help me. Thanks in advance!

```
HTML outside of Django:  
<div id="formContainer"><!--#include virtual="/webform/contact/" --></div>
```

---

```
#Django view
def contact(request):
    if request.method == 'POST': # If the form has been submitted...
        form = ContactForm(request.POST) # A form bound to the POST data

    if form.is_valid(): #All validation rules pass
        # Process the data in form.cleaned_data
        firstName = form.cleaned_data['firstName']
        lastName = form.cleaned_data['lastName']
        street = form.cleaned_data['street']
        city = form.cleaned_data['city']
        state = form.cleaned_data['state']
        zipcode = form.cleaned_data['zipcode']
        phone = form.cleaned_data['phone']
        email = form.cleaned_data['email']
        message = form.cleaned_data['message']

        request.session['fname_ses'] = firstName
        request.session['lname_ses'] = lastName
        request.session['street_ses'] = street
        request.session['city_ses'] = city
        request.session['state_ses'] = state
        request.session['zip_ses'] = zipcode
        request.session['phone_ses'] = phone
        request.session['email_ses'] = email
        request.session['phone_ses'] = phone
        request.session['email_ses'] = email
        request.session['message_ses'] = message

        subject = "A message for _____ from %s %s" %(firstName, lastName)
        message_body = ("Here is the personal information provided by the client: \n"
            "      Full name: %s %s \n"
            "      Address: %s, %s, %s %s \n"
            "      Phone: %s \n"
            "      Email: %s \n \n"
            "Message to you: \n \n%s"
            %(firstName, lastName, street, city, state, zipcode, phone, email, message)
            )
        sender = "email1@example.com"
        recipients = [
            'email1@example.com',
            'email2@example.com',
             email3@example.com',
            ]

        from django.core.mail import send_mail
        send_mail(subject, message_body, sender,
            recipients, fail_silently=False)

        #Redirect after POST
        #reverse() redirects straight to the view instead of the URL
        #Use reverse() to prevent URL from appending to current address
        return HttpResponseRedirect('webform/thanks_simple.html')
        #return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('webform:thanks'))
else:
    form = ContactForm() # An unbound form
return render(request, 'webform/contact.html', {'form': form,})
```

---

```
#contact.html within Django
    <p>We welcome your questions & comments</p>
    <p>Please fill out the form below and hit 'Submit'</p>
    <form action="{% url 'webform:contact' %}" method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ form.non_field_errors }}
            <table>
                        <tr><th><label for="id_firstName">First Name:</label></th><td>{{ form.firstName.errors }} {{ form.firstName }}</td></tr>
                        <tr><th><label for="id_lastName">Last Name:</label></th><td>{{ form.lastName.errors }} {{ form.lastName }}</td></tr>
                        <tr><th><label for="id_street">Street:</label></th><td>{{ form.street.errors }} {{ form.street }}</td></tr>
                        <tr><th><label for="id_city">City:</label></th><td>{{ form.city.errors }} {{ form.city }}</td></tr>
                        <tr><th><label for="id_state">State:</label></th><td>{{ form.state.errors }} {{ form.state }}</td></tr>
                        <tr><th><label for="id_zipcode">Zipcode:</label></th><td>{{ form.zipcode.errors }} {{ form.zipcode }}</td></tr>
                        <tr><th><label for="id_phone">Phone:</label></th><td>{{ form.phone.errors }} {{ form.phone }}</td></tr>
                        <tr><th><label for="id_email">Email:</label></th><td>{{ form.email.errors }} {{ form.email }}</td></tr>
                        <tr><th><label for="id_message">Message:</label></th><td>{{ form.message.errors }} {{ form.message }}</td></tr>
            </table>
        <p><input type="submit" value="Submit" /></p>
    </form>
```

UPDATE: [Django returning 403 Error -- "CSRF cookie not set"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21743232/django-returning-403-error-csrf-cookie-not-set)

I discovered this working solution and decided to just disable CSRF protection on these views. I'm going to continue to see if I can test break the site again. Once that is done, i'll deem  `csrf_exempt` as the solution. Ideally keep protection on would be best, but the form I'm using doesn't really need it and I've been at this for too long.

Answer (score 0):

This is an example django template snippet for your form view. Make sure you have {% csrf_token %} within form tags.

```
<form action="/webform/contact/" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}
    <input type="submit" value="{% trans 'Create' %}" />
</form>
```

Comment: I updated my original post to include my original contact.html. Thanks for the help but that is not an issue I'm having. I know to put csrf_token in form and tried other methods like @ensure_csrf_token on my view. My problem is when I click the submit button, it brings me to the CSRF error page, which still occurs when I used your snippet.

Answer (score 0):

I think the reason is cached page doesn't return csrf token cookie, thus csrf middleware raises error not finding it..
The visible solution is using JS..:
that is sending ajax request to server and return csrftoken if absent.
js on success takes csrftoken from response header, pls see the docs: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/csrf/#ajax 
and updates all forms (I have several on every page) csrfmiddlewaretoken input values to the csrf.
This is one time operation, as the next time csrf token remains in cookies.

Hope there is a better solution, but this one works.